# How to use two different kind of states for the same provider

Tags: flutter, state, provider, state-management, riverpod

I'm using riverpod and I want my provider to handle bookmarking pages.

**By which we have two states to deal with:**

Our fab button (boolean state).

And our bookmarks pages (list state).

When you bookmark a page the fab button is supposed to change icon, but then when you head back, you have a list of bookmarked pages which is supposed to update.

As far as I know you can only make provider class return one type of state object, so how can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: return a class that keeps two states (properties)

Comment: Why can't the fab value be derived from the bookmarks state?

Comment: @pskink can you elaborate more?

Comment: you can simply do something like `ref.watch(bookmarkedPagesProvider).contains(page)` to set the boolean state of your fab button